# Getting users and groups form WLS to Custom Page

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic12c

I have configured users and groups in security realm using SQL Authenticator in WLS 12c.

Eg: ADMIN is a user and MANAGER is group in WLS and I have mapped ADMIN user to MANAGER group.

when I login using the wls user (ie.ADMIN), it gets navigate to corresponding custom page and I can get user using following EL `#{securityContext.userName}`
    or java code:

```
ADFContext adfCtx = ADFContext.getCurrent();  
SecurityContext secCntx = adfCtx.getSecurityContext();  
String user = secCntx.getUserPrincipal().getName();  
String userName = secCntx.getUserName();
String[]  Roles = secCntx.getUserRoles();
```

Similarly I want capture the group for the currently logging user ie. ADMIN and output should be MANAGER.

I used EL as `#{securityContext.userRoles}` for getting the role and kindly help me to get the user group during login time.

Expected OUTPUT should be MANAGER and my output is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a NULL output because the securityContext doesnt contain an object called "userRoles" in ADF Bindings.

The securityContext el expression contains the following value :

- Authenticated
- regionViewable
- taskflowViewable
- userGrantedPermission
- userGrantedRessource
- userInAllRoles
- userInRole
- userName

Since you seems to know all the expected roles you can display MANAGER doing something like :

```
<af:outputText value="{securityContext.userInAllRoles[‘MANAGER’]?'MANAGER':'NOT MANAGER'}" id="ot_1"/>
```

or using the rendered attribute :

```
<af:outputText rendered="{securityContext.userInAllRoles[‘MANAGER’]}" value="MANAGER" id="ot_1"/>
<af:outputText rendered="{securityContext.userInAllRoles[‘EMPLOYEE’]}" value="EMPLOYEE" id="ot_2"/>

...
```

Side note :

- userInAllRoles['ROLE1','ROLE2'] return true if the user have ROLE1 and ROLE2
- userInRole['ROLE1','ROLE2'] return true if the user have ROLE1 or ROLE2